# UIPageViewController not reloading current viewController after foreground app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, background-foreground

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WCCH.jpg
While swiping on pageViewController I press lock or home button. After foreground app in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

I sent notification to pageViewController, so I cant get current controller, PageViewController not reload his controllers.

```
ContentViewController *viewController = [self.viewControllers firstObject];
```

return wrong object. Any delegates method don't call after foreground. How can I get the current controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current viewcontroller might not be the `lastObject` why not 'reload'(don't know what does this mean?) all viewcontrollers in `self.viewControllers`

Or when pageViewController get the notification setViewControllers again

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction
                  animated:(BOOL)animated
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Comment: > not be the lastObject
my bad, typo.